# I have a conflict merge problem with bitbucket

Tags: java, import, bitbucket, pull, merge-conflict-resolution

I try to pull a commit into the main branch with Bitbucket but i had a conflict problem with my code and the merge branch.
like with the import for example

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import com.iadaptime.NewServer.IAdaptimeService.CommandLineResultFromRobot;
import com.iadaptime.NewServer.IAdaptimeService.CommandLineToRobot;
+<<<<<<< destination:8f3750eba03ad7b4ecdf73646bddc2c8e13a850e
+=======
+import com.iadaptime.NewServer.IAdaptimeService.CascadeCopyBoRecordsAction;
+import com.iadaptime.NewServer.IAdaptimeService.CascadeCopyBoRecordsResult;
+>>>>>>> source:41d7353bedd07c292567a6156c99ae6b03248a6c
import com.iadaptime.NewServer.IAdaptimeService.Node;
import com.iadaptime.NewServer.IAdaptimeService.WebCreateRecordAction;
import com.iadaptime.NewServer.IAdaptimeService.WebCreateRecordResult;
```

I try to remove the 2 conflicts lines but i dont understand why there is a conflict here with the import

Comment: What are the commands you use to resolve conflict? Which merge tool did you use? Do you use a merge tool?

Answer (score 0):

This is an *easy* to resolve conflict, in the sense that if you use a (reasonably) decent merge tool (like `KDiff` for instance) it will solve you the conflict automatically, since it will see that it needs to take the changes from both, it is kind of `append-merge` if you will. The reason of the conflict is because the file took two different evolutions and you have two different pieces of code corresponding to the same line number(s).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using VSCode's Source Control tool for viewing this merge conflict.
If you don't see why there would be a conflict, try pull your remote into a new folder and ensure you're working on a clean environment